# Парсинг и вывод в json

Tags: python, json

начал писать бота для биржи и встрял в очередную проблему.
Как сделать парсинг и нормальную(не в одну строку) запись в файл?

```
from binance_api import Binance
import json
bot = Binance(
        API_KEY='BrhonOi39CvGoaqnkKqBOSmGyZqHkle9cFmNx9dKYZBCad9BcuaL2oL8cedIRigZ',
        API_SECRET='fbzM7U5w7D2QeAMKfoqw7GlfASlpufDFkWhP1ULuVAbGxma1wHgV36efVjn9guOA'
    )
srg = str(bot.account())
parsed = json.loads(srg)
print(json.dumps(parsed, sort_keys=True))
```

(этот скрипт не работает вообще)

binance api: https://github.com/Bablofil/binance-api

Все что я находил гуглением выводит данные в одну строку, а другой скрипт уже настроен на парсинг построчно, должно быть:

```
{
  "makerCommission": 15,
  "takerCommission": 15,
  "buyerCommission": 0,
  "sellerCommission": 0,
  "canTrade": true,
  "canWithdraw": true,
  "canDeposit": true,
  "updateTime": 123456789,
  "balances": [
    {
      "asset": "BTC",
      "free": "4723846.89208129",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
      "asset": "LTC",
      "free": "4763368.68006011",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from binance_api  import Binance
import json
import time
bot = Binance(
         API_KEY='BrhonOi39CvGoaqnkKqBOSmGyZqHkle9cFmNx9dKYZBCad9BcuaL2oL8cedIRigZ',
         API_SECRET='fbzM7U5w7D2QeAMKfoqw7GlfASlpufDFkWhP1ULuVAbGxma1wHgV36efVjn9guOA'
     )



local_time = int(time.time())
server_time = int(bot.time()['serverTime'])//1000


shift_seconds = server_time-local_time
bot.set_shift_seconds(shift_seconds)

srg = bot.account()

print(json.dumps(srg, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, вчера весь день потратил в поисках нормального способа записи в файл json, уже почти сдался, ведь при каждой строке кода вылазит миллион ошибок. но теперь есть хоть какая-то надежда